# Text-align: center and align-items: center not working horizontally

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

This has never been the case to me before. I tried `text-align: center` on all sorts of places and they all don't work. They work vertically but they don't working horizontally. I'm trying to get it work both horizontally and vertically for each box.

**This is my code:**

```css
.boxes {
  height:100%;
}
.box {
  width: 33%;
  height: 20%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.box p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.box1 {
  background: magenta; 
}
.box2 {
  background: cyan;
}
.box3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.box4 {
  background: orange;
}
.box5 {
  background: purple;
}
* { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabletest.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box box1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
      <div class="box box2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
      <div class="box box3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
      <div class="box box4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
      <div class="box box5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm also trying to stick to percentage to have a responsive design.

EDIT: This may seem like a duplicate to another post, but my question here is how do I get the texts aligned directly in the center (both vertically and horizontally) while keeping the order of the boxes.

Comment: SO you need the colors to fill the page with text at center?

Comment: Leo the lion, regarding the possible duplicate, that post was asking about how you can arrange the blocks vertically, but my question is how do I get the texts to be aligned in the center of the box as my usual solution isn't working. I don't see how it is similar.

Comment: Deepak, the colours don't necessarily have to fill the page, but I do want the text to be at the center of the boxes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use this solution using flexbox.

**What was changed?**

- Added [`flex-direction: column`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-direction-column) to `.boxes` to define how the flex items (`<p>` element) are placed in the flex container (`.boxes`).
- Added [`align-items: center`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center) to center the flex items along the horizontal axis.
- Added [`justify-content: center`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-justify-content-center) to center the flex items (`<p>` element) on the vertical axis.

```css
* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}

.boxes {
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 33%;
}
.box1 {
  background: magenta; 
}
.box2 { 
  background: cyan;
}
.box3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.box4 {
  background: orange;
}
.box5 { 
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box box1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
  <div class="box box2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
  <div class="box box3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
  <div class="box box4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
  <div class="box box5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why the code presented solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score 10):

Just add

```
justify-content: center;
```

to your `box` class.

That's all you need to do. See [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqYVKL).

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 .box p {
    align-items: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following options

```
.boxes {
height:100%;
}
.box {
  width: 33%;
  height: 20%;
}
.box p {
  text-align: center;
}
.box1 {
  background: magenta; 
}
.box2 {
  background: cyan;
}
.box3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.box4 {
  background: orange;
}
.box5 {
  background: purple;
}
* { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}
```

Note: i used text-align insted of align-items

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for both vertical and horizontal center alignment, whereas text-align only gives me a horizontal center alignment. I did find the answer to my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also just this:

```
.box p {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.boxes {
  height:100%;
}
.box {
  width: 33%;
  height: 20%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  position: relative;
}
.box p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.box1 {
  background: magenta; 
}
.box2 {
  background: cyan;
}
.box3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.box4 {
  background: orange;
}
.box5 {
  background: purple;
}
* { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem like it works. This shows up: http://imgur.com/a/cBKlc . I did find the answer to my question though.